# Firebase getReactNativePersistence not working during jest tests

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, asyncstorage

When I test my React Native app that un my firebase config file

```
const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
    persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
});
```

I get the error message: `Cannot find module '@firebase/auth/react-native' from 'node_modules/firebase/auth/react-native/dist/index.cjs.js'`

The app works fine in runtime, but doesn't seem to work during tests.

Any ideas to what this error could be caused by?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue this morning. Did you get it resolved?

I found that creating a file in the **mocks**  directory called  @firebase/auth/react-native.js  and exporting a named function  getReactNativePersistence  resolved the issue (for now) for me. It's just a dummy function at this point, but my tests run.

```
__mocks__/@firebase/auth/react-native.js

export const getReactNativePersistence = () => {
  return;
};
```